# For Loop stays at 1 when it should increment to 12

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

The user puts in a date (format xx/xx/xxxx) via a field in the Excel spreadsheet named "Kosten_Baten". The program goes through a set of routines to check the format. They all work.

Then it extracts the month (as an integer) out of the user's date and VLOOKUP()s the Dutch 3 character abbreviation for that month, followed by the next 11 months, and puts those (concatenated with the year) in their own column. Each of those columns is separated by 5 other columns which contain other data) (hence kostencol = kostencol + 6).
This will have to be repeated 12 times (once for every month in the year).

`For teller1 = 1 to 12` doesn't increment. When using `debug.print`, `teller1` remains 1.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim testvar As Variant
Dim RPSM As String
Dim Isdigit As Boolean
Public mypass As String
Dim jaar As Integer 'jaar is Dutch for year)
Public maanddagen As Integer
Dim countrow As Integer
Dim KBcol As Integer
Dim WrkCell As Variant
Public CountCol As Integer
Public teller1 As Integer  'teller is Dutch for counter
Public teller2 As Integer
Public maandnaam As String 'maandnaam is Dutch for monthname
Public kostencol As Integer '

        If IsDate(Worksheets("Kosten_Baten").Range("$A$2")) Then
            teller2 = Month(Worksheets("Kosten_Baten").Range("$A$2"))
            jaar = Year(Worksheets("Kosten_Baten").Range("$A$2"))
            Worksheets("Defaults").Activate
            kostencol = 1
            For teller1 = 1 To 12
                If teller2 = 13 Then
                    teller2 = 1
                End If
                maandnaam = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(teller2, Worksheets("Defaults").Range("$F$2:$G$13"), 2, False)
                If teller1 = 1 Then
                    jaar = Year(Sheets("Kosten_Baten").Range("$A$2"))
                Else
                    jaar = Year(ActiveSheet.Cells(14, teller1))
                End If
                maandnaam = Trim(maandnaam) & " " & Str(Trim(jaar))
                Worksheets("Kosten_baten").Cells(3, kostencol).Value = maandnaam
                kostencol = kostencol + 6
                teller2 = teller2 + 1
            Next teller1

            Worksheets("Kosten_Baten").Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("$B$7").Select
        Else
            Call Wrongformat
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Comment: Mandatory question, but where exactly did you put `Debug.Print teller1`?

Comment: Every procedure starts with (`Private, Public or nothing...`) `Sub...` or `Function...`. Where does your procedure start? You cannot use `Public` inside a procedure yet if the variables are declared outside the procedure, `Dim` and `Public` are the same. Please elaborate.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. Again, sorry for my "rookieness" 2) I have put the "Debug.Print teller1 inside the For Next loop. 1) @VBasic2008 -- If I understand you correctly I should never  put a "Dim" outside of a procedure, right? The procedure starts with Sub ChangeDat() followed by a series of If then (else)  End If statements (to check if the date format is right - they all work fine). Then comes the chunk of code I posted earlier, followed by End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You can try a slightly different approach:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngUserDate As Range, userDate As Date, baseDate As Date
    Dim i As Long, rngOut As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Kosten_Baten")
    Set rngUserDate = ws.Range("$A$2")
    
    If IsDate(rngUserDate.Value) Then
            
        userDate = rngUserDate.Value                              'get the user-entered date
        baseDate = DateSerial(Year(userDate), month(userDate), 1) 'first of month...
        
        Set rngOut = ws.Cells(3, 1)                            'start output here
        For i = 1 To 12
            If i > 1 Then baseDate = DateAdd("m", 1, baseDate) 'add a month
            rngOut.Value = Format(baseDate, "mmm yyyy")       'use Format for month name
            Debug.Print i, rngOut.Address, rngOut.Value
            Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(0, 6)                   'six cols to right
        Next i
        
    Else
        Wrongformat 'use of Call is deprecated...
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Debug.Print output:

```txt
 1            $A$3          1/1/2022 
 2            $G$3          2/1/2022 
 3            $M$3          3/1/2022 
 4            $S$3          4/1/2022 
 5            $Y$3          5/1/2022 
 6            $AE$3         6/1/2022 
 7            $AK$3         7/1/2022 
 8            $AQ$3         8/1/2022 
 9            $AW$3         9/1/2022 
 10           $BC$3         10/1/2022 
 11           $BI$3         11/1/2022 
 12           $BO$3         12/1/2022
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for  responding to my question and once again I apologise for my "rookiness"

Comment: You should not apologize - we all started somewhere.  Did that help you figure it out?

Comment: Hello, thank you for  responding to my question and once again I apologise for my "rookiness". I replaced my code with yours. When inserting "debug.print i" in the for next loop it shows nicely from 1 to 12 in the immediate window. However when  inserting "debug.print rngOut.Value" at that same spot it only displays "Jan 2021" (using 01/01/2021 in the input field)- once - no other months. I don't see why it doesn't work ..

Comment: Added a debug.print line and the output when I run it.

Comment: Hello again :) As you can see I added a debug print + the result. What I don't understand it why it only displays the monthname the first time? Also why at the first iteration (i=2) it moves 12 columns, afterwoods it moves 6, as intended ..

Comment: i: 1 monthname: Jan 2022 address: $A$3 columnnumber: 1
i: 2 monthname:  address: $L$3 columnnumber: 12
i: 3 monthname:  address: $R$3 columnnumber: 18
i: 4 monthname:  address: $X$3 columnnumber: 24
i: 5 monthname:  address: $AD$3 columnnumber: 30
i: 6 monthname:  address: $AJ$3 columnnumber: 36
i: 7 monthname:  address: $AP$3 columnnumber: 42
i: 8 monthname:  address: $AV$3 columnnumber: 48
i: 9 monthname:  address: $BB$3 columnnumber:54
i: 10 monthname:  address: $BH$3 columnnumber:60
i: 11 monthname:  address: $BN$3 columnnumber:66
i: 12 monthname:  address: $BT$3 columnnumber:72

Comment: It's pretty difficult to read anything like this posted as a comment - you can/should edit your question to add it there.  That said - my code exactly as posted gave me the output shown below the code: if that's not the case when you use the exact same code I can't account for that difference.  If you can share a workbook with the problem I can take a look, but otherwise it's difficult for me to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. I will share the workbook, but where and how do I do that so that you are the only one who gets it? In any case, your code is below my commented out code, in the Changedat() procedure. The only thing that differs is the added debug.print line

Comment: You will also need the password, I believe..

Comment: I didn't realise you sent email. Did you send it to ronny.sigo@gmail.com?

Comment: No I'm waiting for you to send *me* a mail with your workbook or a link I can use to access it...

Comment: I sent you the email 11 hours ago.. sender is ronny.sigo@gmail.com. Hope you got it ...

Comment: Yes I got it - will get back to you later...

Comment: For anyone coming along later - problem was due to merged cells interfering with the column offsets...

Comment: Hello Tim, now it works like a charm .. thank you so much! I guess I would NEVER have found the solution on my own. Now all I have to do is include the VLOOKUP function (because I want the monthnames to be in Dutch, not English -- ex. May = Mei - Oct = Okt)